# MySql выборка по совпадению записей двух таблиц и сортировка по максимальному совпадению.

Tags: множества, php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть две таблицы с одинаковыми полями.

```
profile1: id, id_user, height, width, color, education
profile2: id, id_user, height, width, color, education
```

Задача взять одну любую запись из profile1. R ней подобрать похожие записи из таблицы profile2 и сортировать по наиболее похожим.

Похожесть определяется по совпадению полей height, width, color, education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам помогут [`CROS JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) и функция [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if). Суть такова: вы получаете декартово произведение двух таблиц, для каждой строки вычисляете количество совпадающих полей и сортируете по количеству совпадений.

```
select p2.id,
       if(p1.width = p2.width, 1, 0) +
       if(p1.height = p2.height, 1, 0) +
       if(p1.color = p2.color, 1, 0) +
       if(p1.education = p2.education, 1, 0) as matching_fields
from profile1 p1
cross join profile2 p2
where p1.id = 6
order by matching_fields desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/417c25c/9

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Просто выручили.